# Image change when i scroll gridview

Tags: android, android-asynctask

GridView load images from URL. When i scrolls gridview, more image chance, how to do fix it... I have tried imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), gridView.invalidateViews().. I have not found a solution to this problem.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;   
    private ArrayList<NodeFood> listImage = new ArrayList<NodeFood>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<NodeFood> listImage){
        this.mContext = c;
        this.listImage = listImage;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        ProgressBar progress;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listImage.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }

    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(arg1 == null){
            holder  = new ViewHolder();
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            arg1    =   mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_grid, null);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageItemGrid);
            holder.progress = (ProgressBar)arg1.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            holder.progress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            arg1.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
        }
        holder.imageView.setTag(arg0);
        holder.progress.setTag(arg0);
        NodeFood a = this.listImage.get(arg0);
        String URL = a.getSRC();
        task_LoadIMG bb = new task_LoadIMG(URL,holder);
        bb.execute();
        return arg1;
    }   

    public class task_LoadIMG extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>{
        private String url;
        private ViewHolder holder;
        public task_LoadIMG(String url, ViewHolder holder){
            this.url = url;
            this.holder = holder;
        }
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try{
                URL aURL = new URL(this.url);
                URLConnection connect = aURL.openConnection();
                connect.connect();

                InputStream is = connect.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                bis.close();
                is.close();
                return bm;
            }catch(IOException e){
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            holder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was facing same problem with listview, when I scroll-down listview and then scroll-up the images were changing randomly. Then I used [THIS CODE FOR IMAGE DOWNLOADER](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html), just try it. May be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `AsyncTask` is taking longer to load an image than that image is being displayed for. Once it's finished downloaded, that cell has come and gone and has been recycled for the next image.

To work around this, store the URL of the cell's image in the cell's `tag` property. Then, check to make sure that the cell URL is the same when the `AsyncTask` completes. If it's not the same, then the cell has been recycled in the meantime and you should discard the update. Here's some code:

```
public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if(arg1 == null){
        holder  = new ViewHolder();
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        arg1    =   mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_grid, null);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.imageItemGrid);
        holder.progress = (ProgressBar)arg1.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        holder.progress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        arg1.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
    }
    NodeFood a = this.listImage.get(arg0);
    String URL = a.getSRC();
    holder.imageView.setTag(URL);
    task_LoadIMG bb = new task_LoadIMG(URL,holder);
    bb.execute();
    return arg1;
}   

public class task_LoadIMG extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>{
    private String url;
    private ViewHolder holder;
    public task_LoadIMG(String url, ViewHolder holder){
        this.url = url;
        this.holder = holder;
    }
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try{
            URL aURL = new URL(this.url);
            URLConnection connect = aURL.openConnection();
            connect.connect();

            InputStream is = connect.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
            return bm;
        }catch(IOException e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (url.equals(holder.imageView.getTag()) {
            holder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        } else {
            // View was updated in the meantime, ignore the image
        }
    }
}
```

You might also consider canceling the `AsyncTask` as soon as the cell is recycled to save bandwidth/CPU cycles. That's left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

I use volley and you can get rid of all async task, tags ...

relapse your ImageView with com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView

something like:

```
<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
android:id="@+id/twitter_avatar"
android:layout_width="48dp"
android:layout_height="48dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginRight="6dip"/>


private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
```

`private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;`

then:

```
final int memClass = ((ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).getMemoryClass();

    // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
    final int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;
    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in bytes rather than number of items.
            return bitmap.getByteCount();
        }

    };

    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

        public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
            mMemoryCache.put(url, bitmap);
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
            return mMemoryCache.get(url);
        }
    });
```

Use Volley:

```
NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ivGridViewImage);

image.setImageUrl(url, mImageLoader);
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with my `GridView`. Although there are not many item, only 24, and I loaded images from my phone's SD card instead of online, I was still getting images jumping all around when I scrolled, which was really only a line or two that was hidden from view at a time.

What I did was simply add a `ViewHolder` and it was fixed. Looks like this [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html) implements it similarly as @scompt.com. His point in the tutorial is that with the `ViewHolder` like this, a call to `findViewById()` is not repeatedly called when the view gets recycled. This might be why the images don't jump around anymore when scrolling.

Not sure if this would help others in the same predicament. I searched on S.O. for this problem and very few addressed it. Hope it helps someone.

**In my adapter class:** `PhotoGridItem` is my model class, that is typed into my `ArrayAdapter` extension, like this: `ArrayAdapter<PhotoGridItem>`. Just to explain my code a bit.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid_view);
            // stores holder with view
            row.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        PhotoGridItem photoGridItem = getItem(position);

        if (photoGridItem != null) {
            bm = photoGridItem.getImage();
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

            // positioning the image in the GridView slot
            holder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (270, 270));
        }

        return row;

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
    }
```