# Images are changing in ListView while scrolling in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview

I have an ImageView in a ListView, the ImageView has a default image and while rendering, I asynchronously download images and load them into ImageViews. It works perfectly, but when I scroll down two items and scroll back, then the default images in the first and second row changing to the image of the sixth and seventh row.

I read these topics, but didn't find the solution.

[Image change when i scroll gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814154/image-change-when-i-scroll-gridview)

[My images changing during scroll in listview android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563923/my-images-changing-during-scroll-in-listview-android)

[ListView images changing During Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155162/listview-images-changing-during-scroll)

```
public class RssAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final List<SyndEntry> items;
private static Context context;
private static Map<String, Bitmap> mBitmapCache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

public RssAdapter(Context context, List<SyndEntry> items) {
    this.items = items;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id) {
    return id;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.rss_item, null);
        holder.itemTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        holder.itemPubDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemPubDate);
        holder.itemImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemImg);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.itemTitle.setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.itemPubDate.setText(items.get(position).getPublishedDate().toString());

    List<SyndEnclosure> encls = items.get(position).getEnclosures();
    if(!encls.isEmpty()){
        holder.imageUrl = encls.get(0).getUrl();
    }

    if (!encls.isEmpty() && holder.imageUrl != null && !holder.imageUrl.equals("null")) {
        holder.setImage(holder.imageUrl);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView itemTitle;
    TextView itemPubDate;
    ImageView itemImg;
    String imageUrl;

    public void setImage(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        Bitmap imageBitmap = mBitmapCache.get(imageUrl);
        if(imageBitmap!=null){
            itemImg.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        } else {
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.get(imageUrl, null, fileHandler);
        }
    }

    FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler fileHandler = new FileAsyncHttpResponseHandler(context) {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, File file) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, File response) {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(response.getPath());
            itemImg.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            mBitmapCache.put(imageUrl, imageBitmap);
        }
    };
}
```

I tried to set a boolean variable to check whether my image was set or not and also tried to use SharedPreferences, but this part of my code didn't run when the image changing.

```
    if(!encls.isEmpty()){
        holder.imageUrl = encls.get(0).getUrl();
    }

    if (!encls.isEmpty() && holder.imageUrl != null && !holder.imageUrl.equals("null")) {
        holder.setImage(holder.imageUrl);
    }
```

Comment: If you need to implement it for production I would strongly suggest you to use a library (picasso or glide)

Comment: Follow this link this will works [See this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36563923/my-images-changing-during-scroll-in-listview-android)

Comment: @MilanPansuriya Thanks, I read that before, but didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I solved the problem finally, I post the solution for the future. So, at this part of code

```
} else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

the `holder` object is not that which has to be rendered for the given row. Thus we have to set the parameters of the `holder` object for the required values. And it was ok, but I didn't set the image related parameters to null if there was no image. So, the two else part were missing:

```
    if(!encls.isEmpty()){
        holder.imageUrl = encls.get(0).getUrl();
    } else {
        holder.imageUrl = null;
    }

    if (!encls.isEmpty() && holder.imageUrl != null && !holder.imageUrl.equals("null")) {
        holder.setImage(holder.imageUrl);
    } else {
        holder.itemImg.setImageResource(R.mipmap.news_icon);
    }
```